# How to get time elapsed since creation date of an object(post) in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, datetime, django-views

I tried looking through the documentation for a datetime formating that would allow me to show the time elapsed since a post was created e.g "created 15s ago" but I couldn't find one. I figured I had to create a custom filter but I don't have a clue on how to go about it. I am also new to the Django framework unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Django has a [**`|timesince`** template tag <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/builtins/#timesince), this formats the time since an event in a "human" way. You thus can format this in the template with:

```
{{ post.created|timesince }} ago
```

For example:

```
>>> print(Template('{{ foo|timesince }} ago').render(Context({'foo': datetime(2021, 2, 20, 21, 15)})))
0 minutes ago
>>> print(Template('{{ foo|timesince }} ago').render(Context({'foo': datetime(2021, 2, 20, 21, 14)})))
1 minute ago
>>> print(Template('{{ foo|timesince }} ago').render(Context({'foo': datetime(2021, 2, 20, 21, 10)})))
5 minutes ago
>>> print(Template('{{ foo|timesince }} ago').render(Context({'foo': datetime(2021, 2, 20, 20, 10)})))
1 hour, 5 minutes ago
```

Since Django runs as backend, this will however *not* update the content if the page does not refresh. For more dynamic ways, you should look for a JavaScript library where you thus pass the datetime in a standardized way, and let JavaScript fill in the amount of time that has passed.

Comment: Worked very well. I'll read the documentation more thorough next time. I don't know how I missed it.